# Android/Java : Annual countodwn with having to update it constantly

Tags: java, android, date

I want to set up a countdown timer to the end of the year, every year, without having to update the year value. In javascript, to get the countdown date, it would be:

```
var date = new Date();
var deadline = ' December 31 ' + date.getFullYear();
var t = Date.parse( deadline ) - Date.parse( new Date() );
```

How would I implement this in java?
(Yes, I know java and javascript are not related, I just made it happen in javascript but couldn't figure it out for java, just started learning java....)

Code:

```
        Calendar endOfYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        endOfYear.setTime(new Date(0)); /* reset */
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        double t =  endOfYear.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();

        double seconds = Math.floor( ( t / 1000 ) % 60 );
        double minutes = Math.floor( ( t / 1000 / 60 ) % 60 );
        double hours = Math.floor( (t / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ) % 24 );
        double days = Math.floor( t / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );

        System.out.printf(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds\n");
```

Output:

```
03-24 18:16:05.177 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 54.0 seconds
03-24 18:16:06.180 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 53.0 seconds
03-24 18:16:07.182 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 52.0 seconds
03-24 18:16:08.184 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 51.0 seconds
03-24 18:16:09.187 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 50.0 seconds
03-24 18:16:10.190 1800-1800/com.ehlien.clevercash I/System.out: 282.0 days, 1.0 hours, 43.0 minutes and 49.0 seconds
```

But it's 5 hours off. Where it should be 6 hours, it shows 1 hour...

Comment: Take a look at the [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class source {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Calendar endOfYear = Calendar.getInstance();
         endOfYear.setTime(new Date(0));
         endOfYear.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
         endOfYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
         endOfYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
         Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
         long t =  endOfYear.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
         long seconds =  ( t / 1000 ) % 60 ;
         long minutes =  ( t / 1000 / 60 ) % 60;
         long hours =  (t / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ) % 24 ;
         long days = t / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
         System.out.printf(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds\n");
    }
}
```

This will product:

```
280 days, 18 hours, 47 minutes and 41 seconds
```

Comment: The idea is not to put in the year value like 2014, so when the year ends the year updates itself to the current or next year.

Comment: You have to put something in the year value. So in that case, you can take system time value and count from that point.

Comment: I updated the question with the slight error I'm getting.

Comment: Please give an upvote if you like the answer. Thank you

Comment: Lol I can't. Need 15 reps